# How to insert unicode characters to table with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, unicode

My database config file is set to

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';

$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

my MySQL database info as

Type      = `MyISAM`

Collation = `utf8_general_ci`

But when I insert record to table it shows ????? question marks.

Comment: Is your HTML (view) page has set `<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">` ?

Comment: I added                                                           <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"> tag

Comment: Don't forget that you will need to save the view page as UTF-8 as well.